# how to add my theme content King composer wordpress page builder plugin?

Tags: wordpress

How to add custom theme content in kingcomposer wordpress page builder plugin?I want to add custom content in kingcomposer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily integrate KingComposer plugin in your custom theme. Follow below instruction-

This instruction helps you integrate your website with any theme and KingComposer page builder.

**Admin elements**

1. Install Kingcomposer plugin via page added plugin
2. Creat file and include via function.php in your theme

I created file kc_element.php in folder inc/kc_element.php

I call it via file function.php

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/kc_element.php';

```
global $kc;
    $kc->add_map(
        array(
            'element_id' => array(
                'name'        => __( 'Text Title', 'domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Display text and description', 'domain' ),
                'category'    => __( 'Twenty_Sixteen', 'domain' ),
                'icon'        => 'fa-header',
                'params'      => array(
                    array(
                        'name'        => 'title',
                        'label'       => __( 'Title', 'domain' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'description' => __( 'Insert text title', 'domain' ),
                        'value'       => 'Insert Title',
                        'admin_label' => true
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'        => 'desc',
                        'label'       => __( 'Description', 'domain' ),
                        'type'        => 'editor',
                        'description' => __( 'Text description', 'domain' ),
                        'value'       => base64_encode( 'Insert Content' )
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

**Front-end elements:**

1. Creat shortcode file and include via function.php in your theme

I created file kc_shortcode.php in folder inc/kc_shortcode.php

I call it via file function.php

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/kc_shortcode.php';

```
add_shortcode( 'element_id', 'element_Function' ); 

function element_Function( $atts ){ 

    $title = $desc = '';
    extract( $atts );

   echo $title;
   echo $desc;

}
```

Check it know more about King Composer plugin.
Available all type in king composer plugin http://docs.kingcomposer.com/getting-started/installation/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easy add your post type by follow code:

```
global $kc;
// add single content type
$kc->add_content_type( 'your-post-type-name' );
// add multiple content types
$kc->add_content_type( array( 'type-1', 'type-2' ) );
```

Hope that make sense.

Comment: You can get more details from document site http://docs.kingcomposer.com/